# Semaphores notation - why V and P instead of S and W

Tags: language-agnostic, history, semaphore

I am asking this question because I'm trying to get the notation to stick in my head. My lecturer said that V and P are the first letters of the dutch words for signal and wait, but this is not true.

Does anyone know what words V and P abbreviate or did Dijkstra just pick his favorite two letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Wikipedia's [Semaphore (programming) article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29#Function_name_etymology) and a [copy of Dijkstra's work](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd00xx/EWD74.PDF):

- *Probeer te verlagen* (P) means 'try to decrement'
- *Verhogen* (V) means 'increment'

P has the *Proberen...* (try) term in front of the meaningful *verlagen* (decrement) term because the Dutch words for increment and decrement both start with "V". Dijkstra added the "try to" words in front of the meaningful "decrement" term so that there would be a simpler way of distinguishing between the two functions.

Comment: Yes, they're from Dijkstra, but Wikipedia's [Semaphore (programming) article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Function_name_etymology) claims he meant "_prolaag_" and "_verhogen_", citing his original paper (in Dutch) at http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd00xx/EWD74.PDF.  We are very lucky that Dijkstra left such a well-recorded career behind him.  Now if only my Dutch were good enough to read that paper :-)

Comment: From the same Wikipedia article: The word "*prolaag*" is not a real word- it is a portmanteau of "*probeer te verlagen*" or "try to reduce (decrement)". The words *verlagen* and *verhogen* were so similar that he added "try..." to the beginning of the "decrement" term to distinguish the semaphore operations.

Comment: I've also heard the much better Dutch mnemonics *pak* (take) and *vrij* (free).